# How can i modify the printf output of a struct in a file?

Tags: c

im learning c, so im working in a temperature logger, i finished the program, but now im trying to make it more pretty, the system shows a list of measures, there are 4 measures per date, this is the output of the code:

```
Fecha      Hora      Medición

20/09/2022 06:30     200.0 °C

20/09/2022 12:30     200.0 °C

20/09/2022 18:30     200.0 °C

20/09/2022 22:30     200.0 °C

21/09/2022 06:30     190.0 °C

21/09/2022 12:30     190.0 °C

21/09/2022 18:30     190.0 °C

21/09/2022 22:30     190.0 °C

23/09/2022 06:30     190.0 °C

23/09/2022 12:30     190.0 °C

23/09/2022 18:30     190.0 °C

23/09/2022 22:30     190.0 °C

25/09/2022 06:30     150.0 °C

25/09/2022 12:30     150.0 °C

25/09/2022 18:30     150.0 °C

25/09/2022 22:30     150.0 °C

Pulse una tecla cualquiera para salir...
```

and this is the code that shows the values:

```
void listado(void){
    struct s_mediciones medicion;
    FILE *mediciones;

    if((mediciones=fopen("mediciones.txt","r"))==NULL){
        printf("\nError al abrir/crear el archivo.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    system("cls");
    printf("Fecha      Hora      Medici%cn\n", 162);
    fread( &medicion, sizeof(medicion), 1, mediciones);
    while (!feof(mediciones)){
        printf("%10s ",    medicion.fecha_med);
        printf("%1s ",    medicion.hora_med);
        printf("%9.1f %cC ",     medicion.temp, 248);
        printf("\n");
        fread( &medicion, sizeof(medicion), 1, mediciones);
    }
    printf("\nPulse una tecla cualquiera para salir...\n");
    getch();
    fclose(mediciones);
    system("cls");
}
```

The problem is that i dont know how to print 4 values, and print (---------) to separate the diferent dates, how can i do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: [Why should I not load images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I don't understand how you want it to look in the end. Could you give an example of how you want it to look like?

Comment: Please upload the text of your code and text of the output, rather than images

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Of course!, here is an example:
date time value
date time value
date time value
date time value
-----------------
date1 time value
date1 time value
date1 time value
date1 time value
------------------

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Sorry for the bad formatting, the idea is to insert a line after 4 dates

Comment: I meant, edit the original post to include your code and the (in text form, not as an image), and also to include the output (in text form, not as an image)

Comment: Suggest replacing `while (!feof(mediciones)){` with `while(fgets(medicion, sizeof(medicion), mediciones)){...`  This will read a line of the file, and allow the code to parse lines one-at-a-time.  It is [problematic to use feof to control a loop](https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046476070&id=1043284351)

Comment: @ryyker Thanks!, i will have that in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to seperate with a "---------" after 4 dates. You could do:

```
void listado(void)
{
    struct s_mediciones medicion;
    FILE *mediciones;

    if((mediciones=fopen("mediciones.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError al abrir/crear el archivo.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    
    system("cls");
    printf("Fecha      Hora      Medici%cn}\n", 162);
    fread(&medicion, sizeof(medicion), 1, mediciones);
    int count = 0;
    while(!feof(mediciones))
    {
        if(count % 4 == 0)
        {
            printf("------------------------------\n");
            count++;
        }
        printf("%10s ", medicion.fecha_med);
        printf("%1s ", medicion.hora_med);
        printf("%9.1f %cC ", medicion.temp, 248);
        printf("\n");
        fread(&medicion, sizeof(medicion), 1, medicines);
    }
    printf("\nPulse una tecla cualquiera para salir...\n");
    getch();
    fclose(mediciones);
    system("cls");
}
```

Edit:

@ryyker suggests that you replace `feof()` with `while(fgets(medicion, sizeof(medicion), mediciones))`

The code would be like this:

```
void listado(void)
{
    struct s_mediciones medicion;
    FILE *mediciones;

    if((mediciones=fopen("mediciones.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError al abrir/crear el archivo.");
        getch();
        exit(1);
    }
    
    system("cls");
    printf("Fecha      Hora      Medici%cn}\n", 162);
    int count = 0;
    while(fgets(medicion, sizeof(medicion), mediciones) != NULL)
    {
        if(count % 4 == 0)
        {
            printf("------------------------------\n");
            count++;
        }
        printf("%10s ", medicion.fecha_med);
        printf("%1s ", medicion.hora_med);
        printf("%9.1f %cC ", medicion.temp, 248);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nPulse una tecla cualquiera para salir...\n");
    getch();
    fclose(mediciones);
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Nice!, i put the count in the printf("\n", cont++) and now it works fine!, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @ManuMontesino Happy if I could help